# vnc - black and white hatching

Tags: vnc

I'm trying to use tightvnc viewer on my windows machine to login to my ubuntu pc. I'm running vncserver on ubuntu. I can login ok but all I see is black and white hatching.

Any ideas?

Comment: What desktop session are you trying to use? have you created a suitable ~/.vnc/xstartup file?

Comment: (The black and white hatching is probably the default root window (background) pattern of the X server)

Comment: To expand on @VolkerSiegel 's comment - that's what happens if you don't have a a default X session and you connect to X without a window manager to prettify everything... read as a giant X for a cursor; ugly windows; and a background of alternating black and white, black and gray, or white and gray dots.